# Access UI without hang

Tags: c#, wpf

One of the method in my program access UI elements continuously and writes a file. This makes my UI stuck for sometime. I need to play a loading gif image during this time. But the image appears only after the task is completed.

How do i change this code so that my app will without hanging UI?

```
private void BCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ImgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RegUser));
    newWindowThread.Start();
}

private void RegUser()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        //method body
         .....           
        ImgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }));
}
```

Comment: You're running all of your code on the UI thread.  Why do you make a background thread and then never do anything on it?

Comment: Can you post more code and tell us what your overall goal is for the method? odds are there is a much better way to do this.

Comment: @SLaks, bro I've already coded 90% for my project. This is really an additional feature. Changing that code for background is little difficult for me

Comment: @user3858462: Then you're stuck.  Just because it's hard to do it right doesn't mean there is a magical way to run code on the UI thread without freezing the UI.

Comment: @Wobbles, There are some textblocks in my form. The method RegUser() reads the values and writes it into an excel file. During the file write, my UI stuck until it completes. This should not be happen

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
private void RegUser()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ImgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }));
    //method body
    .....           
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ImgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }));
}
```

Only invoke methods which access UI.

Consider to use `InvokeAsync` for something to happens, but not immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is same as my question. I have to put all codes that access UI as you are posted. How can this method RegUser() access any UI component freely without hanging UI?

Comment: Your mistake was to invoke **whole method** into UI thread. Combination `Thread` + `Invoke` nullify each other, as *any code* in `Invoke` will runs in UI thread (effectively blocking it). Instead of putting whole *method body* into invoke, you have to put it into thread and *only invoke* small parts, which doesn't hand UI.